# Java EE Servlet получить информацию c какого браузера был запрос

Tags: java-ee, servlet

Как через `HttpServletRequest` или `HttpServletResponse` получить с какого браузера был сделан запрос? Или может есть другой способ получить эту информацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Информацию об устройстве пользователя можно получить из заголовков запроса `HttpServletRequest`

```
request.getHeader("user-agent");
```